# Sharing callbacks between different widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using FirebaseAuth in my Flutter app. And I am trying to use verification with a phone number. The idea is to have one page for the user to enter phone number, and another page to verify the SMS code.

Here's what I have written:

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted:
          (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        showError(
          context: context,
          firebaseAuthException: e,
        );
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => CodeVerification(
                verificationId: verificationId,
                resendToken: resendToken,
                authHandler: authHandler,
              )),
        );
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
    );
```

But when I push another widget (`CodeVerification`) to `Navigator`, I have no knowledge of the `verificationFailed` and `verificationCompleted` callbacks in the second widget.

What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to push Navigator to another route? Can't you create a single route that manage the phone authentication completely? I would create a stateful widget with a `bool` in order to show/hide to code input, when the callback `codeSent` triggers you set it to true.

Following an **untested** example:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PhoneAuthenticationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phoneNumber;

  const PhoneAuthenticationScreen({Key key, this.phoneNumber}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PhoneAuthenticationScreenState createState() => _PhoneAuthenticationScreenState();
}

class _PhoneAuthenticationScreenState extends State<PhoneAuthenticationScreen> {
  final _codeTextFieldController = TextEditingController();
  bool showCodeInput = false;
  String verificationId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          buildSendCodeButton(),
          buildCodeInput(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildSendCodeButton() {
    return RaisedButton(
      child: Text("send code"),
      onPressed: () {
        FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: widget.phoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
          codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) {
            setState(() {
              showCodeInput = true;
              verificationId = verificationId;
            });
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
        );
      },
    );
  }

  buildCodeInput() {
    if (!showCodeInput) return Container();

    return Row(
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _codeTextFieldController,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Submit"),
          onPressed: () async {
            final smsCode = _codeTextFieldController.text;
            PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am trying this kind of solution, but just wanted to know if it was possible.

Comment: Also realized this breaks the Android back button logic.